# Is there a difference between /../ and ../ in php?

Tags: php, directory-structure

I was curious if `../` and `/../` is the same in PHP so I tried these:

```
require_once('/../frame/header.php');
require_once('../frame/header.php');
```

Both of them worked. Was I just lucky or they realy do the same exact thing? Why?

Comment: Are you sure you don't mean `./../` and `../`?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In your context if they both worked, that implies that your scripts are at the root of the filesystem you have access to, or one level in. They are *not* the same however!  `/../` refers to the filesystem root (and `..` one directory up, which just gets eaten and is still the root), while `../` refers to one directory higher than the current one.   *Any path* beginning with `/` is an absolute path from the filesystem root.

From anywhere other than the filesystem root, these would not function equivalently.

Suppose your working directory is `/var/www/scripts`.

```
require_once('../include.php');
```

Will include a file at `/var/www/include.php`.

But from that same location, if you did

```
require_once('/../include.php');
```

...php will attempt to load the file `/include.php` at the filesystem root, and it probably won't exist.

Now, a lot of web hosts will supply you with a filesystem whose root `/` is also the web server's *document root*, the web server *document root* is only one directory level in from the root like `/www`. In that case, `/../` may work fine, but beware if you ever attempt to move it to another server with a different filesystem configuration.

So if the script's working directory was `/www`, just by luck, these two would function the same way:

```
require_once('../include.php');
require_once('/../include.php');
```

Both would include the file `/include.php` at the filesystem root.

*Note, this is not PHP-specific, but a property of filesystems which use the `..` in general...*

Comment: More information about include() file's lookup here: http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.include-path :)

Answer (score 1):

Preceding any link with a / mean that you are coming from the root of the context you are in. If you are already in the root directory, or a chroot jail, then both statements are the same.